# Why does this RSpec describe spec show two different results based on method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, database-cleaner

Given

```
context "stripe customer" do
  subject { @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve @subscription.stripe_customer_token }

  it "show me email" do
    p @customer.email
    p user.email
    @customer.email.should == user.email
  end

  #its(:email) { should == user.email }
  its(:description) { should == user.email }
end
```

In the `it` block, this passes. The commented out #its portion does not pass. I get two different objects.       `expected: "daniel3@example.com"
            got: "daniel133@example.com" (using ==)`

Is this due to `database_cleaner` gem? Some way I'm not setting up factories/database_cleaner properly?

Why would it not match in the its block but does in an it block? How can it be different?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `subject` in an odd way: you're using it to set an instance variable, rather that using it as the thing against which expectations are made.

The block given to `subject`is evaluated lazily: it is only evaluated when your spec uses subject. For your `its` example, rspec calls `subject` for you, but for your other example you never call `subject`, so the `@customer` used is probably a hangover from an enclosing context